# Passing C functions and parameters as rvalue references

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, templates, c++11

I'm trying to retrofit two pieces of legacy code. One of the pieces implements a timeout for a function call. So far it's been used on C++ methods and works perfectly.

Now, there's a requirement to implement a similar timeout to an older C library. I'm trying to use the same code for this, but running into issues.

Here's a simplified version of the code, with the problem I'm facing.

```
uint32_t myFunc1()
{
    return 0;
}

uint32_t myFunc2(uint32_t a)
{
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t dummy = 1;
    timedCall(myFunc1); //compiles fine. 
    timedCall(myFunc2, dummy); //compile errors C2672, C2893
}

template <class F, class... Args>
uint32_t timedCall(F &&f, Args&&... a)
{
    try
    {
        std::packaged_task<uint32_t(Args...)> myTask(std::bind(f, a...));
        auto res = myTask.get_future();
        std::thread(std::move(myTask), a...).detach(); //This is where the issue is.        

        //Do other stuff
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        //handle exceptions
    }

    return 0; //return something
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
C2672   'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found
C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'
```

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Can you reduce the code down to the keast required to generate the error?  What exact version of msvc are you using?  Are there no other error messages?  Usually it gives context.

Comment: Compiles fine with Clang in C++11 or C++14 mode.

Comment: @Yakk, sorry, should have been more specific. I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @amol I did say "exact".  Update what?

Comment: @JohnZwinck, you're right, it builds with VS2015 as well. The error occurs in the next line after the get_future() that I inadvertently left out:
    std::thread(std::move(myTask), a...).detach(); //This is where the issue is.

I've updated the sample code.

Comment: @amol that line makes no sense.  You already bound `a...` to `myTask`, and you are passing them again?  Now that I look at it, the packaged task init is also nonsensicle, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with std::thread not accepting the packaged_task, `std::thread(f, a...)` worked fine. Now I would not try shipping in `std::thread` waters (*edit:* where Andrei R. provided a good explanation in detail what went wrong), while [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) will make the task much easier for you:

```cpp
template <class F, class... Args>
uint32_t timedCall(F &&f, Args&&... a)
{
    try
    {
        auto res = std::async
        (
            std::launch::async,
            std::forward<F>(f),
            std::forward<Args>(a)...
        );
        //Do other stuff
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        //handle exceptions
    }

    return 0; //return something
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

when you use `std::bind(f, a...)` you get callable object that can be called with `obj()`. But constructor of `std::packaged_task<uint32_t(Args...)>` expects object callable with `obj(a...)`. Some compilers may ignore extra arguments, though.

You need to either remove `bind`:

```
std::packaged_task<uint32_t(Args...)> myTask(f);
auto res = myTask.get_future();
std::thread(std::move(myTask), std::forward<Args>(a)...).detach();
```

Or to change call syntax:

```
std::packaged_task<uint32_t()> myTask(std::bind(f, std::forward<Args>(a)...));
auto res = myTask.get_future();
std::thread(std::move(myTask)).detach();
```

Or (better) to follow Aconcagua solution

Comment: I recommend adding std::forward to the first solution, too.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It helped me understand what's going on in this code that I had just inherited.